# How create folder in documents app in iPhone folder

Tags: swift, file, ios13, swift5

How can im create folder in documents app.

**Im tried this:**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: String = paths.first ?? ""
let dataPath = documentsDirectory + "/yourFolderName"
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath) {
    try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories:     false, attributes: nil)
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Folder inside iPhone folder:**

[image]

Comment: I don't get the question here, what's the issue? what do you want to achieve, explain it with more context?

Comment: @PawanRai Hello, need create Folder on device in folder iPhone in File's app